# Folder for custom single-{post_type}.php

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

Hello i feel like my WP theme folder is getting abit messy is there a way to put all the custom page-{post_type}.php, and single-{post_type}.php inside a folder insted of having them in the root of the theme?.

And how to make sure WP reads them? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add it in a templates folder then you have to call the template by using below code:

```
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/layout'); ?>
```